# gwenview not starting correctly

Tags: gwenview

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04.  I want to print a png file using **gwenview**. That ought to be trivial; I'd expect that after issuing the command **gwenview** *file-to-view*, **print** would be among the options on the menu.  But it isn't.  So how an I print this file?

Much of the problem may be due to the fact that the program doesn't seem to start with the correct main menu. The correct starting menu menu has File as its first alternative; the menu I get does not have File at all.  That suggests that **gwenview** not starting with the right entry point.  I've encountered that phenomenon before.

Here is a screenshot of what I get when I open **gwenview** on a file:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g74afbokrv2ww07/AACNTlWmgWIW7HosorJ-LiXJa?dl=0

This is what one might expect after starting gwenview on a subsequent screen. It should not be the opening screen.

Sorry this was delayed so long -- I had a hard time figuring how to include a screenshot in this post.

Comment: Under the menu click file and print, or use ctrl+p

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: You forgot to add the link for the screenshot.